# Odd behavior with Selenium while scraping

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a script that extracts the urls from a webpage, loads each link and extracts the data I require. However upon further investigation I find that Selenium isn't opening the link as it should and is duplicating information. eg as follows:

```
link 1 - Title:ABC <-- within link, extract 123
link 2 - Title:DEF <-- within link, extract 456
link 3 - Title:GHI <-- within link, extract 789
link 4 - Title:JKL <-- within link, extract 000
```

the output should be as follows:

```
ABC, 123
DEF, 456
GHI, 789
JKL, 000
```

however the output I get is as follows:

```
ABC, 123
ABC, 123
GHI, 789
JKL, 000
```

this behavior seems to be random.

Here is the code

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(alllinks)
for elem in elems:
    links.append(elem.get_attribute("href"))
    for url in links:
        try:
            time.sleep(0.5) 
            driver.get(url) 
            time.sleep(2)
```

anyone experience this type of behavior ?

EDIT: UPDATE:

An update on this, I have scraped just the URL's 3 times, and compared the results with each other. The URLs are unique and extracted according to the site.
From what I see, its the way Selenium loads the URL's from an array.

Comment: Make sure to have proper synchronization when you are loading the urls. I feel your script got the information from 2nd link load, before the page loaded completly, that's why you are got the duplicate info of 1st link.

Comment: that makes sense, would you suggest using a time.sleep(x) after the page loads to then copy URLs or is there is python / selenium specific command that I could use ?

Comment: are you using `driver.get()` for url navigation?  And is there any common element between all the pages which will displayed once page is loaded?

Comment: post your code!  not everyone can read minds

Comment: I append all the scraped URL's to a variable, then in a for loop iterate over each item using the driver.get() command. code snippet as follows: `elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(alllinks)

for elem in elems:
    links.append(elem.get_attribute("href"))

for url in links:
    try:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thought I'd provide the answer to my question. It wasn't a problem with Selenium, but a problem with my code.
I have a try/except code block that would execute if an element exists, if it does, the variable is appended with the extracted text. however if the element didn't exist, the variable would contain the text from the previous loop and write it to file.

to circumvent this, I have a del  at the end of the for loop - there might be other more elegant ways of doing this, but it does solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your query correctly, You should load the latest href, rather iterating through all hrefs each time.

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(alllinks)
previousTitle = ''
for elem in elems:
    url = elem.get_attribute("href")
    links.append(url)
    driver.get(url) 
    # make sure to wait until the title is changed (no issue until 2 urls have same title)
    wait.until_not(EC.title_is(previousTitle)) 
    previousTitle = driver.title
```

Comment: I don't think there is a problem with synchronization as I ran my script 3 times, and all 3 times the output was duplicated at random points. further to this, the last link wasn't duplicated which indicates that the full URL list was loaded before the first link was loaded to start extraction